# maven dependency error after loss of internet connection

Tags: java, maven

I lost my internet connection while downloading maven dependencies.
Later when i try to update it using the command

```
mvn clean install -U
```

I get the following error:

```
- Failure to transfer edu.mit:jwi:jar:2.2.3 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
     reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact edu.mit:jwi:jar:2.2.3 from/to 
     central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer 
     edu.mit:jwi:jar:2.2.3 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the 
     update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact edu.mit:jwi:jar:2.2.3 from/to central (https://
     repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206) at
```

What can I do to resolve the dependencies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `edu.mit:jwi:jar:2.2.3` `(~/.m2/repository/edu/mit/jwi)` from your local maven repository and try again.